# Config web-app data directory from xml JSF/Java

Tags: java, jsf, app-config

I cannot figure out how to implement this on my application.

I want to have an xml (or some file) where the person in charge of the administration of the app chooses where the Root_Dir is.

Right now it is hard-coded something like `C:\MyAppRootDir` but I want that this path could be modified whenever the admin wants.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to provide external configuration to a webapp.

1. Create a properties file and put it in one of the paths covered by webapp's runtime classpath, or add its path to the webapp's runtime classpath.

   E.g. `/path/to/config.properties` with this content

   ```
   xmlrootdir=C:\MyAppRootDir
   ```

   You'll be able to grab it by the classloader.

   ```
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
   String xmlrootdir = properties.getProperty("xmlrootdir");
   // ...
   ```

   Based on your question history, you're using/targeting Tomcat. The admin could edit the `shared.loader` entry of its `/conf/catalina.properties` to point to the folder where this properties file is located.

   ```
   shared.loader=/path/to
   ```
2. Add a VM argument to Tomcat startup script.

   ```
   -Dconfig.xmlrootdir=C:\MyAppRootDir
   ```

   It's available as follows:

   ```
   String xmlrootdir = System.getProperty("config.xmlrootdir");
   // ...
   ```
3. Set an environment variable.

   ```
   SET CONFIG_XMLROOTDIR=C:\MyAppRootDir
   ```

   It's available as follows:

   ```
   String xmlrootdir = System.getenv("CONFIG_XMLROOTDIR");
   // ...
   ```

Comment: For the first option, I didn't quite understand. Where should I put my properties file? let's say my app's directory is `C:\MyApp` so should I put the properties file in `C:\MyApp\config\file.properties` ? What do you mean by `webapp's runtime classpath`?

Comment: In the given example, it's placed in `/path/to` which translates in Windows to `C:\path\to\ `. It really doesn't matter where exactly as long as it's part of webapp's runtime classpath. If the path is not by default covered by webapp's runtime classpath, then you need to specify the `shared.loader` property accordingly. The default folders covered by webapp's runtime classpath are webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib` and `/WEB-INF/classes` folders and in case of Tomcat also its own `/lib` folder and the JRE's `/lib` and `/lib/ext` folders, but the latter two should generally be untouched.

Comment: The "classpath" is basically a collection of paths, folders or even URIs containing JAR files or Java class files where Java should search around when loading classes. The "runtime classpath" is the one which is to be used by java.exe (so, during runtime). The "compiletime classpath" is the one which is to be used by javac.exe (so, during compiletime).